# I'm using dijit.Editor, how can I detect if a text cursor is at the end (bottom right edge) of its container?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using dijit.Editor and I'm trying to create a multi-page editor.

I am currently monitoring the scrollHeight to see if it exceeds the element height. If it does I am pulling content out from the end until the scrollHeight goes back down.

This doesn't work entirely well. If I could detect that the cursor was at the end of the element then I would know that pressing another character would cause the scrollHeight to exceed the allowed value.

Note that if the cursor is at the end of the text content, this does not mean it is at the end of the container.